# Is it required to provide access_key and secret_key in order to access object from s3 in lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to write a lambda function that would update object file in the s3 bucket.
I am using same account and region in order to implement that. As per the policy, the secret key and access key that to be used would be change frequently, that means i cannot use same secret key and access key in the lambda function to access the s3 object

So is there anyway i can access s3 object with out providing access and secret key in  lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the acl set on the object? if it is set to public read access, you do not have to pass credentials. But make sure those objects does not have security or privacy concerns.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectacl

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without having to pass secret key and access key, by using aws [IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create.html) role.
Assign that role to your lambda trying to access your s3 bucket.
Remember to give your IAM role created for [lambda, permission to access s3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/).